# Given a number field $K$, is there a number field $L$ containing $K$ such that all prime ideals of $K$ are unramified in $L$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, ramification

We know that there is no nontrivial extension $L$ of $K=\mathbb{Q}$ such that all the primes of $K$ are unramified in $L$ (The discriminant $\delta_L>1$).

Suppose that $\mathbb{Q}\subsetneq K$. Can we find an extension $L$ of $K$ such that all primes of $K$ are unramified in $L$ ?

Comment: See this answer: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/76616/unramified-extensions-of-number-fields

Comment: $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-5},i)/\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-5})$ is the standard example.

Comment: Don't you want to take $L$ as being the Hilbert class field of $K$? It is a proper extension of $K$ iff the class number of $K$ is $>1$, i.e. iff $O_K$ is not a PID (iff $O_K$ is not a UFD).